# A R-module Homomorphism such that $f\circ f =f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> If $f: A\to A$ is a R-module homomorphism such that $f\circ f =f$ , then prove that $A= \text{Ker } f \oplus \text{Img } f$.

Now , If $x\in A  $ is in $\text{Ker } f$ then $f(x) =0 =f\circ f(x)=f(0)=0$ but I am unable to get any meaningful information by that and I am unable to find what $\text{Ker } f$ is. Also, I am not able to use $f\circ f =f$ in finding $\text{Img } f$. So, Please help me.

I have been doing a course on Algebraic Geometry where module theory is covered.

Comment: Suggestion, notice that $a=a-f(a)+f(a)$. And that $f(a-f(a))=0$.

Comment: Another way to look at the above: the restriction of the map $f: \text{Img} f \to A$ is a splitting of the short exact sequence $0\to \text{Ker} f \to A \to \text{Img} f \to 0$.